# Playing with loaded geojson makers on mapbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, geojson, mapbox

My problem is more related to JS than to mapbox.

I've loaded [few geojson markers with different dates](http://temp.sharesand.info/prison/index3.html). [The Geojson](http://temp.sharesand.info/prison/mortsPrisons.geojson) format is :

> "Fri Oct 17 01:00:00 GMT+02:00 2008"

I would like to filter markers per years. For the moment i was only able to filter specified value like *return f.properties['LabelName'] === 'Rennes';*

- I thought of playing with regex like this :

> ```
> douze.onclick = function(e) {
>     all.className = '';
>     this.className = 'active';
>     // The setFilter function takes a GeoJSON feature object
>     // and returns true to show it or false to hide it.
>     markerLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
>         // First try wtih reGex on DateTime
>           var stryear = f.properties['DateTime']; 
>           var reg20 = /20\d*/g;
>           console.log(stryear.match(reg20));
>           return f.stryear.match(reg20) === '2012';
>     });
>     return false;
> };
> ```

But it doesn't work. Does the regex return a good value? Mozilla console doesn't help me.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
...
var reg20 = /20\d*/g;
console.log(stryear.match(reg20));
return f.stryear.match(reg20)[0] == '2012';
```

`match()` returns an *array* of matches, so access the first match by adding `[0]`.
Also use `==` to compare values, not `===` which compares objects.